# What is the difference between Vno and Va

Tags: v-speeds

What is the difference between the maximum structural cruising speed (Vno) and the manuevering speed (Va)?  Can you also please explain how these speeds are calculated?

I do understand that Va is set to where the wing will stall before the plane will go over its G limit but what does Vno mean?

Answer (score 3):

Va limits G loads resulting from pilot input of maximum control deflection to limit load.  Vno limits G loads caused by vertical gusts over 30 ft/sec, without pilot input, to limit load.

In other words, Va protects you from bending the wings from pulling too hard, and Vno protects you from bending the wings from going too fast through bumps.

Comment: I have heard Va used in reference to turbulence penetration speed not Vno.

Comment: Turbulence Penetration Speed is Vb.  Vno is Normal Operating and is similar to Vb but seems to be applied only to non-transport a/c.  Transport a/c have Va, Vb and Vmo.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like my question is a duplicate of another answer found [here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/3088/what-protection-does-vno-provide):

Basically to summarize flying below Va guarantees that the plane will stall before exceeding the design load factor.  Vno is more like a guideline as to structural limits that may occur during normal turbulence and does not provide and real protection.